# Java ExceptionHandler whole Class

Tags: java, spring, exception

Is there a way to set a ExceptionHandler for a Class and Exceptionclass?
I have a class like this:

```
public class MyServiceClass {

    public void foo() {
        //some Code... 
        throw new MyCustomRuntimeException();
        //some more Code... 
    }

    public void foo2() {
        //some other Code... 
        throw new MyCustomRuntimeException();
        //more other Code... 
    }
}
```

Now I would like to define a MyCustomRuntimeException - Handler something like this:

```
private void exceptionHandler(MyCustomRuntimeException ex) {
    //some Magic
}
```

Which should be used everytime a MyCustomRuntimeException is thrown in this class. I know I could use try, catch, finally in each method, but is there a Class wide solution? Would like to skip the boilerplate

```
try {
...
} catch (MyCustomRuntimeException ex) {
    exceptionHandler(ex);
}
```

Iam using Spring in this application (no Spring Boot), but I found nothing how to use `@ExceptionHandler` for plain Spring. I tried the following (doesn`t work):

EasyApplication

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class EasyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfiguration.class);
        FooBar foo = context.getBean(FooBar.class);
        foo.doException();
    }
}
```

FooBar

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

public class FooBar {

    public void doException() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

     @ExceptionHandler(value = RuntimeException.class)
     public void conflict() {
         System.out.println("Exception handled!");
     }
}
```

MyConfiguration

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "FooBar")
    public FooBar fooBar() {
        return new FooBar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using spring-mvc and not in a multi-threaded environment, you would be able to do well with the following.

```java
public class ExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("This is from the uncaught");
    }

}
```

And then add this line in your `main` method. This works for small applications, and spring has minimal role here.

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());
```

If you have a bigger application and needs a more elegant solution - look to introduce aspects (AOP) in to your app.

*Edited June 2nd 2020*

---

### This is when spring-mvc is used

You can use `@ExceptionHandler` for this. [Spring Tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

`@ExceptionHandler` can handle both class specific and global handlers (via `@ControllerAdvice`)

The class specific handlers is triggered before global handlers. So best practice is to use `RuntimeException` and `Exception` in global handlers, instead of using them in individual classes. Reduces boilerplate further.

Comment: Yeah I have read that before, but how do I use this without Boot, Controller, RequestMapping and so on? I added a Example Application above.